# Is it possible to have strongly typed HTTP request handlers in Restlet?

Tags: java, restlet

Consider the following `ServerResource` derived type:

```
public class UserResource extends ServerResource {
  @Get
  public User getUser(int id) {
    return new User(id, "Mark", "Kharitonov");
  }
}
```

(Yes, it always returns the same user no matter the given id).

Is it possible to make it work in Restlet? Because, as far as I understand, the expected signature of the GET handler is:

```
Representation get();
```

OR

```
Representation get(Variant v);  // (no idea what it means yet)
```

Now I understand, that I can implement the non type safe GET handler to extract the arguments from the request and then invoke `getUser`, after which to compose the respective `Representation` instance from the result and return. But this is a boilerplate code, it does not belong with the application code, its place is inside the framework. At least, this is how it is done by OpenRasta - the REST framework I have been using in .NET

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the parameter from the signature

```
  @Get
  public User getUser() {
    String id = getQuery().getFirstValue("id");
    return new User(id, "Mark", "Kharitonov");
  }
```

No need to override the get() methods in this case as the @Get annotation will be automatically detected.

Comment: OK, so GET http://bla-bla-bla/user/2 is routed to `getUser` and if we assume that POST http://bla-bla-bla/user gets routed to `newUser`, then `getUser` and `newUser` must not be in the same `ServerResource`, otherwise GET http://bla-bla-bla/user will be routed to `getUser` too! Looks like, despite GET and POST speak of the same resource (`User`) they must be handled by different `ServerResource` instances. This is kinda disappointing...